# ascii code in Linux

Tags: java, linux, ascii

Why <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> gives an ASCII value of 10 (decimal value). It should actually give 13. I am connecting to Amazon EC2 linux instance through putty. I execute the below program

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class NumbersConsole {

private static String ttyConfig;

public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
                setTerminalToCBreak();

                int i=0;
                while (true) {

                        //System.out.println( ""+ i++ );

                        if ( System.in.available() != 0 ) {
                                int c = System.in.read();
                    System.out.println(c);
                                if ( c == 13 ) {
                                        break;
                                }
                        }

                } // end while
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("IOException");
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.println("InterruptedException");
        }
        finally {
            try {
                stty( ttyConfig.trim() );
             }
             catch (Exception e) {
                 System.err.println("Exception restoring tty config");
             }
        }

}

private static void setTerminalToCBreak() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    ttyConfig = stty("-g");

    // set the console to be character-buffered instead of line-buffered
    stty("-icanon min 1");

    // disable character echoing
    stty("-echo");
}

/**
 *  Execute the stty command with the specified arguments
 *  against the current active terminal.
 */
private static String stty(final String args)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String cmd = "stty " + args + " < /dev/tty";

    return exec(new String[] {
                "sh",
                "-c",
                cmd
            });
}

/**
 *  Execute the specified command and return the output
 *  (both stdout and stderr).
 */
private static String exec(final String[] cmd)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    int c;
    InputStream in = p.getInputStream();

    while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
        bout.write(c);
    }

    in = p.getErrorStream();

    while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
        bout.write(c);
    }

    p.waitFor();

    String result = new String(bout.toByteArray());
    return result;
}

}
```

and when I give the input as (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>), I am getting displayed a value of 10. But I am expecting a value of 13. Please let me know if I am missing anything??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The translation of CR to LF is handled by the tty driver.  You're calling `setTerminalToCBreak()`, which manipulates the tty settings (I think it disables the erase, kill, werase, and rprnt special characters).

The `icrnl` setting, which is enabled by default, causes carriage return (CR) to be translated to newline (LF).  Disabling that should let you see CR characters directly.  Setting `raw` mode changes a number of flags, including turning off `icrnl`.  (Figuring out how to do that in Java is left as an exercise.)

But beware of doing this.  The <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> key typically sends a CR character.  Translating it to LF is what allows it to mark the end of a line.  If you turn off that translation, you might break that behavior unless you handle CR yourself.

For more information on tty settings, `man tty` or follow [this link](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stty).

Comment: Correct.  The settings in question are per-user settings (associated with your tty login), not "Linux" per se.  From a command prompt, type "man tty" to learn more.  Or type "stty sane" ;)

Comment: PS: on DOS/Windows, hitting <Enter> generates *two* bytes: a carriage return (13) and a line feed (10).  Similarly, a C, C# or Java program that writes "\n" generates the same two bytes on DOS/Windows.

Comment: @paulsm4 Translating \n to \r\n on Windows is only specified by the C specification and is **not** done in Java (i.e. writing \n in java with the standard classes should really only write one character). No idea about C#.

Comment: Oh before I forget it, the solution: Java5 added %n to the formatting options and there are all the println() functions, so there's hardly ever need to do so. But if you really want to write a newline yourself before Java5, one should use `System.getProperty("line.separator");`

Answer (score 0):

My other answer started on totally the wrong page.

```
  stty ("-cooked")
```

works for me.

Something in the depths of teletype land wants you to have happy little `^J`s instead of `^M`s, but cooking the terminal stops it.

```
       $ stty -cooked ; java -cp /tmp NumbersConsole
       13

       $
```

Back in the Good Ol' Days, some computers (Commodore, Apple) used ^M (13) for their Return key; some (IBM) used a combination ^M^J; others (Unix) used ^J (10).

Now, in the modern world, it's almost always ^J (although I think Windows code still has some legacy ^M^J stuff under the hood sometimes?)

Comment: DOS/Windows remains "Carriage return/Line feed": #13#10

Comment: I don't know if that's a charming throwback to the daisy-wheel printing era, or just a disturbing reminder of same… but then, I forget how spoiled we are on the application level of the stack some days, I'd totally forgotten that HTTP uses ^M^J as well.